# Cant include navbar.html in other modules

Tags: python, html, django, web, navbar

I'm quite a beginner in web development I've encountered some problems using Django

this is my projects modules code.

```
{% include 'navbar.html' %}


<h1>projects template</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 
    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
    Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>

{% endblock content %}
```

and this is my navbar.html:

```
<h1>Logo</h1>
<hr>
```

when I run this, it is expected to return something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCg2l.jpg)

but it instead outputs this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU8YX.jpg)

as you can see it doesn't wrap the navbar text correctly. I would really appreciate it if someone helps me with this issue.

Comment: Can you post your whole template code. It looks like you made a mistake with the Jinja tag syntax somewhere, but cannot see it since you only post part of the code. Normally, the `{%` and `%}` tags should never be displayed in the HTML response.

Comment: By looking at your image it looks like you are opening the `html` file directly  in your browser instead of opening through `Django`.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is include this in your nav bar html file:

```
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
```

then add

```
{% extends 'navbar.html' %}
{% block content %}
<html>
   ...
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

inside your other template

Answer (score -1):

I had opened the HTML directly from my text editor by running the HTML file. so when I open it from a browser everything looks just right